# Order list elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to order a list of strings:

```
MyList = ['dataset1', 'dataset3','dataset2','dataset10','dataset100','dataset11']
```

When I use sorted function

```
X = sorted(MyList)
```

I get

```
['dataset1', 'dataset10','dataset100','dataset11','dataset2','dataset3']
```

I want to get

```
['dataset1', 'dataset2','dataset3','dataset10','dataset11','dataset100']
```

Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that sort, when passed in strings, uses string comparison. You could strip out the dataset, then just sort using integers instead

```
X = sorted(MyList, key=lambda x: int(x.replace("dataset","")))
```

Comment: it's always better to test your answers. Also, it's a very classical & duplicate question